# Laravel request stripping tags

Tags: php, laravel

I sending a payload which contains html (from a wysiwyg field) via axios to a Laravel 8 backend.
I can see the data being sent in the payload;

```
_method: post
message: gvdf<b>gdfs</b>gdfs<div>gf<i>dgdfg</i>dfsg</div><h4>gfdgdfsgdf</h4>
```

When I dump in the controller the tags are missing from the request (`Illuminate\Http\Request`) object.
I can see them in the $_POST superglobal, but not the request object (using input and get).

```
dd($_POST['message'], $request->input('message'), $request->get('message'));
```

Output

```
"gvdf<b>gdfs</b>gdfs<div>gf<i>dgdfg</i>dfsg</div><h4>gfdgdfsgdf</h4>"
"gvdfgdfsgdfsgfdgdfgdfsggfdgdfsgdf"
"gvdfgdfsgdfsgfdgdfgdfsggfdgdfsgdf"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure? Since you're using dd, check the source in the browser to see if the tags are there.

Comment: Verify your middlewares or FormRequest, one of them must be changing your input via a strip_tag() method. Add your App\Http\kernel.php to your question

Comment: should use `xdebug` for better trace and use dump and die separately

Comment: @N69S you got it. Forgot about a middleware applied to the web group that stripped tags!  If you want to post as an answer I can give your the rep for the credit

Comment: @Rooneyl, just close the question for being unreproducible

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @N69S there was a middleware in the web middleware group that was stripping tags.
As the offending middleware was only not wanted on that one route, it can be removed using

```
Route::post('my-post', 'PostController@login')->withoutMiddleware(['sanitize_input']);
```